# match a pattern ignoring white space and select the group in between

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am unable to match the pattern as required due to string containing JS with similar pattern as exclusion or delimiters.
The code sample is here [samplecode](https://jsfiddle.net/m_sunils/ndb8oa50/7/)

I have tried the following regex match patterns

```
^[}\s*)\s*(\s*{\s*](?<data>.+)([}\s*)])*$

^[^\(]*\((?<template>.+)\)\s*\((?<data>.+)\)[^\)]*$
```

The expected result is in between the comments

/****************data to be extracted - start***************/

/****************data to be extracted - end***************/

```
(input => {

    var chartWrapper = $("<div></div>").appendTo("#container")
        .attr("id", "chart_wrapper");
    var chartDiv = $("<div></div>").appendTo("#chart_wrapper")
        .attr("id", "chart_div");
    $('#chart_wrapper').append(`<style>
#chart_wrapper{ 
 width:1240px;
height:688px;
position:relative;
padding: 35px 30px 20px 30px;
box-sizing:border-box; 
}
</style>`);  

    var tempBrandGroup = ((function () {
        var marketsharecolors = [
            "#f59031",
            "#363636"
        ];

        var group = {};
        group.name = uniqueCategory.map((value) => {
            return value;
        });


        var _counter = 0;

        group.brands = input.dataSeries.map(function (dataitem) {
            var dataitem_obj = {};
            dataitem_obj.brand_name = dataitem.name;
            dataitem_obj.power_in_mind = dataitem.pim;
            dataitem_obj.market_share = {};
            dataitem_obj.market_share.value = dataitem.marketShare;
            dataitem_obj.market_share.color = marketsharecolors[_counter];
            dataitem_obj.baseSize = dataitem.baseSize;

            if (_counter === 0) _counter = 1;

            dataLabels.forEach(function (motivationalFactor, index) {
                dataitem_obj[motivationalFactor] = {};
                var motObj = dataitem.brandData.filter((item)=> item.name == motivationalFactor)
                dataitem_obj[motivationalFactor].value = motObj[0].value;
            })
            return dataitem_obj;
        })
        return group;
    })());

})({

/****************data to be extracted - start***************/
   "title":"Overview of Brand Imagery",
   "chosenBrand":"Brand A",
   "motFactorsRefBaseSize":"20",
   "brandsRefBaseSize":"30",
   "dataSeries":[
      {
         "name":"BrandA",
         "category":"Your Business",
         "brandData":[
            {
               "name":"Motivation factor 6",
               "value":50,
               "baseSize":20,
               "tanimotoGroup":2
            },
            {
               "name":"Motivation factor 7",
               "value":41,
               "baseSize":50,
               "tanimotoGroup":1
            }           
         ],
         "pim":"50",
         "marketShare":"23",
         "baseSize":"20"
      }
      ]
 /****************data to be extracted - end ***************/  
})
```

Comment: Would not be easier to remove comments instead of matching the content in between?

Comment: Do you want to match it like this? `^\/\*{2,}[^*]+\*{2,}\/((?:\r?\n(?![\t ]*\/\*{2,}).*)*)\r?\n[ \t]*\/\*{2,}[^*]+\*{2,}\/$`  https://regex101.com/r/yL7DRX/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird the `/*...*/` parts seem to be highlights for the post itself, so your answer might not be that useful in its current form. If you look at the first pattern, it is looking for the `})({` part, then tries to capture something what is *not* in the post (a `<data>` tag perhaps?), so right now it is not necessarily possible to answer the question at all.

Comment: @tevemadar I see, you could be right about that. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: OP: if this page(?) is coming from a template engine, it may look rather different when it gets processed and arrives to the client.

Comment: Thanks guys for the responses so far, as @tevemadar pointed i have put the comments only to highlight the portion of json to be extracted. However i will be getting the entire string as input and i just need to separate out whats in the first part ie; (input=>{ <?template>}) and ({ <?data> }). The first part was not a problem as i am able to extract everything upto }){( but extracting the JSON bit is proving troublesome as the input contains IIFE and similar patterns, though  {)({ is the only certain delimiter which has to be matched with spaces till end of file.

Comment: FYI, the entire content is read from a blob storage as a string and then I have a requirement to separate out the <template> and <data> parts into two files. I need a pattern to match the <?data> part. Thanks